# How to auto fill a specific complex formula after inserting new row to a defined Excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been looking for a way to automatically insert a row, where a column contains an Index(Match) formula.

I've looked at several tutorials and forum where it says formulas should auto populate because it's part of the Excel table function, especially if auto-fill feature is enabled. However, my formula is the following, and will not process.

```
=INDEX('Lookup Tables'!$M$20:$M$26,(MATCH(**H2**,'Lookup Tables'!$N$20:$N$26,0)))
```

This formula is in Cell G2. Adding info into cells G3, G4 would make the following formula on the column to the right.

```
=INDEX('Lookup Tables'!$M$20:$M$26,(MATCH(**H3**,'Lookup Tables'!$N$20:$N$26,0))),

=INDEX('Lookup Tables'!$M$20:$M$26,(MATCH(**H4**,'Lookup Tables'!$N$20:$N$26,0)))
```

Basically, when a new value is entered on H3, H4, H5, etc, the =index(match) formula should automatically populate, but this doesn't work.

I thought of just adding an =iferror(*Formula*," ") but that just expands the table indefinitely and adds too many blank columns (my table has over 20 columns).

Only way I could think was to write a VBA script, but I'm stuck on what to do or where to even start.

Comment: In G2 there is a formula, ok. Based on this statement : " Adding info into cells G3, G4 would make the following formula on the column to the right. " what is in G3 (a data or formula) ?  | Any screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to attach an image to this comment. In G3, it's basically text. (eg. 'Waste', 'Fill', etc ... and H3 is the index match formula above. So in the lookup table you got:

`Waste   
Fill         
x            
y on G column.
Pad Dump 1 2 on H column
etc...`
When you type in H3 'Pad', in G3 would automatically populate 'Waste', and it does this for every row. I want to lock down the G column, so I would like this automated and the only way I could think of was with a macro.

Comment: You may upload the pic at any cloud storage service and share the link by editing the above question. (look for the 'edit' button)

Comment: So G3 is the input text.. and H3 is the formula.. ok. Since that is the set up.. this : "When you type in H3 'Pad', in G3 would automatically populate 'Waste' " will not happen. right ?